# Property name in Bindings case insensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I was debugging a piece of code and to my surprise the following lines both worked correct.

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Text", myObject, "PropertyName");

Binding binding = new Binding("Text", myObject, "propertyname");
```

It seems that the property name is case-insensitive, but I cannot find anything about this.

Can anybody tell me if I am missing something, or what could be the rational behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where it is documented, but it is in [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Binding.cs#2880aa40d35efb14#references) indeed.

It uses a `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to compare the property name from the binding with the actual object's property:

```
if( tempPropInfo==null
    &&
    String.Equals (propInfos[i].Name, propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  )
  {
  }
```

Comment: Interesting find. Looking at the code I can't help but wonder what horror would happen when adding four properties to a class: FooBar, fooBar, Foobar and foobar. And set the binding to: `FOOBAR`

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: Yes indeed. That will break the entire system. Not sure why they did it, maybe for those VB.NET users?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: That is exactly the reason why I thought I was missing something. But now I would still like to know why this is implemented like this.

Comment: @Marco: Give a call to the design team ;)

Comment: Hopefully superfluous: I do not recommend having public properties/fields that only differ in casing...

Comment: Lol. That would be very bad practice indeed.